# Powershell cmdlet differences for the same operation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I have got three commands for the same operation from documentation.
These commands copies a file from `azure data lake store` to local machine.
I am not able to understand whether these are aliases or different commands.

1. Export-AdlStoreItem
2. Export-AzDataLakeStoreItem
3. Export-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem

Please help

Comment: [Get-Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Export-AdlStoreItem` is an alias of `Export-AzDataLakeStoreItem`, which belongs to the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) powershell module `Az.DataLakeStore`.

Use this to check:

```
Get-Command Export-AdlStoreItem -ShowCommandInfo
```

[image]

The `Export-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem` belongs to the old [`AzureRm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) powrshell module `AzureRM.DataLakeStore`, it is a different command from the ones before.

Comment: Actually we posted at the same time, I didn't knew about your answer, let me remove mine.

Comment: @JagratiModi-AIS Well, just two minutes before yours, you're a nice man.;-)

Comment: @JoyWang when new versions are relased, does the existing modules gets replaced with a new module or how does it work

Comment: @TomG The old `AzureRm` module also works currently, but it will not be updated any more, so I will recommend you to use the new `Az` module, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-4.2.0) to migrate it from `AzureRm` to `Az`.